# Use jQuery Dialog with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have been using jQuery to build dynamic dialogs for taking user input. 
Dynamic in the sense that the html content of the dialog is not defined in the html page.

For instance :

```
    showPasswordDialogConfirmUser: function (callback) {
        $('<div></div>').dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: "Enter Password to connect to Dynamix !",
            open: function () {
                var markup = '<input type="password" id="dynamixUserPassword"/>';
                $(this).html(markup);
            },
            buttons: {
                'Forgot ?': function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    Dynamix.binding = false;
                    Dynamix.bound = false;
                    PairingUtils.clearAllCookies();
                    Dynamix.bind();
                },
                'Connect': function () {
                    callback($('#dynamixUserPassword').val());
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I have been trying to do something of this sort in jQuery Mobile but I cant find anything that works. jQM needs the html content of the popup to be predefined in the page but I do not have access to the html page. I've also tried using jQuery UI and jQM together but it messes up a lot of the ui stuff.

Any workarounds ?

JS Fiddle Sample : https://jsfiddle.net/tgL1n4je/3/

The dialog doesn't show up on using jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile together.

Comment: Hi there, care to recreate the problem via jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: Updated with a JS Fiddle.

Comment: Hey @Shivam, if my answer did indeed answer your question, please consider modifying your title to say something along the lines off....  `onclick` stopped triggering dialog... This is so this question might help others with the same problem :)

Comment: Although it might not be the best way of writing the js, the click listener still fires :) If you check out the console, it logs a message. It doesnt show up the dialog.

Comment: You are right, let me have a look at it again :) BTW, it's the best way to write jQuery, not JS :)

Comment: Yep, but they need the popup html to be pre defined in the page. I need to create popups dynamically.

Comment: Okay, I'll post you an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79672/discussion-between-jason-nathan-and-shivam-verma).